# Latex: Trouble with \label and \ref in texmaker

Tags: latex, label, ref, texmaker

I think I know how to use \label{...} and \ref{...}
But after changing the tex-file to pdf I have no possibility to click the refers. Once I get it. There were red frames around the clickable words, but i forget how I did this. There are to many possibilies to transform the tex-file. Which should I use to get the correct output? (I hope you understand the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things: (a) `\usepackage{hyperref}` and (b) you can find lots of tex users at [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Nobody write about using this package :( I lost 4 hours of my life.